# [Flutter][Android] java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (24.4.1)

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

As for my env: Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.9, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-x64, locale en-JP)

I upgraded firebase related packages using the same code and now the app crashes.
The output in the event of a crash is as follows

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (24.4.1).
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$3(AsyncQueue.java:539)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.run(:2)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8064)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1026)

Caused by java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1039KB
       at com.google.protobuf.Utf8$DecodeUtil.access$400(Utf8.java:1854)
       at com.google.protobuf.Utf8$SafeProcessor.decodeUtf8(Utf8.java:976)
       at com.google.protobuf.Utf8.decodeUtf8(Utf8.java:341)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.decodeStringRequireUtf8(ArrayDecoders.java:213)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.decodeMapEntryValue(MessageSchema.java:4430)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.decodeMapEntry(MessageSchema.java:4467)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseMapField(MessageSchema.java:4683)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseProto3Message(MessageSchema.java:5439)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFrom(MessageSchema.java:5481)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.mergeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:271)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseOneofField(MessageSchema.java:4784)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseProto3Message(MessageSchema.java:5447)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFrom(MessageSchema.java:5481)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.mergeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:271)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.decodeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:241)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.decodeMapEntryValue(MessageSchema.java:4418)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.decodeMapEntry(MessageSchema.java:4475)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseMapField(MessageSchema.java:4683)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseProto3Message(MessageSchema.java:5439)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFrom(MessageSchema.java:5481)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.mergeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:271)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseOneofField(MessageSchema.java:4784)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseProto3Message(MessageSchema.java:5447)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFrom(MessageSchema.java:5481)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.mergeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:271)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.decodeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:241)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.decodeMapEntryValue(MessageSchema.java:4418)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.decodeMapEntry(MessageSchema.java:4475)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseMapField(MessageSchema.java:4683)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseProto3Message(MessageSchema.java:5439)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFrom(MessageSchema.java:5481)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.mergeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:271)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseOneofField(MessageSchema.java:4784)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseProto3Message(MessageSchema.java:5447)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFrom(MessageSchema.java:5481)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.mergeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:271)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.decodeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:241)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.decodeMapEntryValue(MessageSchema.java:4418)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.decodeMapEntry(MessageSchema.java:4475)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseMapField(MessageSchema.java:4683)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseProto3Message(MessageSchema.java:5439)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFrom(MessageSchema.java:5481)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.mergeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:271)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseOneofField(MessageSchema.java:4784)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseProto3Message(MessageSchema.java:5447)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFrom(MessageSchema.java:5481)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.mergeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:271)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.decodeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:241)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.decodeMapEntryValue(MessageSchema.java:4418)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.decodeMapEntry(MessageSchema.java:4475)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseMapField(MessageSchema.java:4683)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseProto3Message(MessageSchema.java:5439)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFrom(MessageSchema.java:5481)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.mergeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:271)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseOneofField(MessageSchema.java:4784)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseProto3Message(MessageSchema.java:5447)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFrom(MessageSchema.java:5481)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.mergeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:271)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.decodeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:241)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.decodeMapEntryValue(MessageSchema.java:4418)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.decodeMapEntry(MessageSchema.java:4475)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseMapField(MessageSchema.java:4683)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseProto3Message(MessageSchema.java:5439)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFrom(MessageSchema.java:5481)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.mergeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:271)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseOneofField(MessageSchema.java:4784)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseProto3Message(MessageSchema.java:5447)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFrom(MessageSchema.java:5481)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.mergeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:271)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.decodeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:241)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.decodeMapEntryValue(MessageSchema.java:4418)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.decodeMapEntry(MessageSchema.java:4475)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseMapField(MessageSchema.java:4683)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseProto3Message(MessageSchema.java:5439)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFrom(MessageSchema.java:5481)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.mergeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:271)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseOneofField(MessageSchema.java:4784)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseProto3Message(MessageSchema.java:5447)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFrom(MessageSchema.java:5481)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.mergeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:271)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.decodeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:241)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.decodeMapEntryValue(MessageSchema.java:4418)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.decodeMapEntry(MessageSchema.java:4475)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseMapField(MessageSchema.java:4683)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseProto3Message(MessageSchema.java:5439)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFrom(MessageSchema.java:5481)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.mergeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:271)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseOneofField(MessageSchema.java:4784)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseProto3Message(MessageSchema.java:5447)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFrom(MessageSchema.java:5481)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.mergeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:271)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.decodeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:241)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.decodeMapEntryValue(MessageSchema.java:4418)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.decodeMapEntry(MessageSchema.java:4475)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseMapField(MessageSchema.java:4683)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseProto3Message(MessageSchema.java:5439)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFrom(MessageSchema.java:5481)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.mergeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:271)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseOneofField(MessageSchema.java:4784)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseProto3Message(MessageSchema.java:5447)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFrom(MessageSchema.java:5481)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.mergeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:271)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.decodeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:241)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.decodeMapEntryValue(MessageSchema.java:4418)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.decodeMapEntry(MessageSchema.java:4475)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseMapField(MessageSchema.java:4683)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseProto3Message(MessageSchema.java:5439)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFrom(MessageSchema.java:5481)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.mergeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:271)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseOneofField(MessageSchema.java:4784)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseProto3Message(MessageSchema.java:5447)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFrom(MessageSchema.java:5481)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.mergeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:271)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.decodeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:241)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.decodeMapEntryValue(MessageSchema.java:4418)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.decodeMapEntry(MessageSchema.java:4475)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseMapField(MessageSchema.java:4683)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseProto3Message(MessageSchema.java:5439)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFrom(MessageSchema.java:5481)
       at com.google.protobuf.ArrayDecoders.mergeMessageField(ArrayDecoders.java:271)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseOneofField(MessageSchema.java:4784)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.parseProto3Message(MessageSchema.java:5447)
       at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.mergeFrom(MessageSchema.java:5481)
       at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.parsePartialFrom(GeneratedMessageLite.java:1673)
       at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.parseFrom(GeneratedMessageLite.java:1762)
       at com.google.firestore.v1.Write.parseFrom(Write.java:778)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.decodeOverlay(SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java:221)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.lambda$getOverlay$0$com-google-firebase-firestore-local-SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache(SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java:60)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.apply(:4)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLitePersistence$Query.firstValue(SQLitePersistence.java:529)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.getOverlay(SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java:60)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalDocumentsView.getDocument(LocalDocumentsView.java:91)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalDocumentsView.getDocumentsMatchingDocumentQuery(LocalDocumentsView.java:275)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalDocumentsView.getDocumentsMatchingQuery(LocalDocumentsView.java:262)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.QueryEngine.executeFullCollectionScan(QueryEngine.java:248)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.QueryEngine.getDocumentsMatchingQuery(QueryEngine.java:90)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.executeQuery(LocalStore.java:844)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.initializeViewAndComputeSnapshot(SyncEngine.java:218)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.listen(SyncEngine.java:209)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.EventManager.addQueryListener(EventManager.java:104)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$listen$7$com-google-firebase-firestore-core-FirestoreClient(FirestoreClient.java:177)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.run(:4)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$enqueue$2(AsyncQueue.java:441)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.call(:2)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1(AsyncQueue.java:327)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(:4)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:463)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:234)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

heartbeat-information-executor:
       at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:458)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1123)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

ConnectivityThread:
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:161)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

ReferenceQueueDaemon:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:442)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:568)
       at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:232)
       at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:140)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

awaitEvenIfOnMainThread task continuation executor1:
       at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:433)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1063)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1123)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:64)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

flutter-worker-1:
       at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:463)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:361)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:939)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1123)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

Okio Watchdog:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout.awaitTimeout(AsyncTimeout.java:325)
       at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout.access$000(AsyncTimeout.java:42)
       at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$Watchdog.run(AsyncTimeout.java:288)

GmsDynamite:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:442)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:568)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:2)

firebase-installations-executor-2:
       at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:458)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1123)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

Measurement Worker:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:442)
       at in.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@224417045@22.44.17 (190408-0):7)

FinalizerWatchdogDaemon:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:442)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:568)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepUntilNeeded(Daemons.java:385)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:365)
       at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:140)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

firebase-installations-executor-1:
       at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:458)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1123)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

FinalizerDaemon:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:442)
       at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:203)
       at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:224)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:300)
       at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:140)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

ScionFrontendApi:
       at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:458)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1123)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

OkHttp ConnectionPool:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at com.android.okhttp.ConnectionPool$1.run(ConnectionPool.java:106)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

pool-13-thread-2:
       at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:463)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:361)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:939)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1123)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

pool-13-thread-4:
       at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:463)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:361)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:939)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1123)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

pool-13-thread-5:
       at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:463)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:361)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:939)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1123)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

flutter-worker-0:
       at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:463)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:361)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:939)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1123)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

com.google.firebase.crashlytics.startup1:
       at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:433)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1063)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1123)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:64)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

Crashlytics Exception Handler1:
       at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(VMStack.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1841)
       at java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Thread.java:1909)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsReportDataCapture.populateThreadsList(CrashlyticsReportDataCapture.java:295)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsReportDataCapture.populateExecutionData(CrashlyticsReportDataCapture.java:266)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsReportDataCapture.populateEventApplicationData(CrashlyticsReportDataCapture.java:216)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsReportDataCapture.captureEventData(CrashlyticsReportDataCapture.java:102)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.SessionReportingCoordinator.persistEvent(SessionReportingCoordinator.java:274)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.SessionReportingCoordinator.persistFatalEvent(SessionReportingCoordinator.java:127)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController$2.call(CrashlyticsController.java:203)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController$2.call(CrashlyticsController.java:188)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker$3.then(CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.java:105)
       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zze.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:64)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

AsyncTask #1:
       at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:461)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:361)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.take(SynchronousQueue.java:922)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1063)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1123)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)


...
```

What I tried：

- Add proguard

```
-keep class io.grpc.** {*;}
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```

- Add "shrinkResources" and "minifyEnabled" to build.gradle
- downgraded the package

still crashing..

Comment: do you have any update on it